# Multi-column grid with variable number of different height children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to make a screen that displays items in the following manner:

1. The "columns" have two items in them **such that the odd items are on the left in the column**
2. The items are varying heights, but fixed width. This causes there to be a **variable number of items in each column**.
3. The "columns" wrap to the right to avoid scrolling

[Variable-sized items in a grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZYxE.png)

So far, I've tried leveraging both `display: flex;` and `display: grid` but am unable to get either to achieve the above image. The flex method does not display the items in the order I want. The grid method forces items in the same row to have the same height as the longest element.

[Example with flex](https://jsfiddle.net/kodonnell_heila/sn05wxte/21/)

[Example with grid](https://jsfiddle.net/kodonnell_heila/d8to1uhj/39/)

So, is there a way to do this with just CSS? I'm not opposed to using javascript to achieve this, but I'd rather use CSS if possible.

Comment: Not with CSS-Grid as it will create equal height rows. Probably not with Flexbox either unless you have literal column wrappers.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read the guides before posting. Main improvement here is to provide some concise code examples directly as part of the question, since your jsfiddle links may expire some day.